# Xamarin.Forms app brokes up after migration to Net Standard 2.0

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

In these days I'm trying to port my xamarin.forms app from a sared project strategy to a Net Standard xamarin.forms app. I've followed this brief guide (without succes): https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/under-the-hood/net-standard/

For now I'm delevoping only the android version, I'm using Xamarin.Forms v2.5.0.91635 and I've already updated the android SDKs (api level from 23 to 26).
I've also installed the latest version of dotnet core: 2.0.3

The app compiles without a single problem and is deployed on the phone. 
The problems rise when is started: it crashes, no exception is thrown and no explanation is given by the debug console.
I've tried to set a breakpoint on the first instruction inside the OnCreate of the MainActivity.cs but apparently it chrashes before executing any line of code.

Does anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the **Android Device Monitor** to check what happened?

Comment: I've tried now, but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Can you include logs from Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we've found the main problem after days of searching.

It seems that NuGet for android projects has some difficulties to resolve the dependencies of the packages that installs. 
When we've added xamarin.forms to our Net Standard project, it was installed without his android dependecies ( do not ask me why). After installing all these dependencies, the app works fine like the old times.

Thanks for the help. I hope this could be useful for someone!